# Check if a Swift object is a generic that conforms to a specific protocol

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I am trying to come up with a model for fields in a form. There is a parent "Field" class, with a generic for the type, and then subclasses for the different types of fields. Here is the main Field class with its relevant protocol:

```
protocol FieldProtocol {
    var stringRepresentation: String { get }
}

class Field<T>: FieldProtocol {
    var value: T

    var stringRepresentation: String {
        return "\(value)"
    }

    required init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Then I have a subclass that is a text field:

```
class TextField: Field<String> {
    required init(value: String) {
        super.init(value: value)
    }
}
```

Also, I want a field that can use any Enum as the field, as long as the enum conforms to a certain protocol:

```
protocol EnumProtocol {
    var rawValue: String { get }

    static func getValueFromString(value: String) -> EnumProtocol
}

class EnumField<T: EnumProtocol>: Field<T> {
    override var stringRepresentation: String {
        return value.rawValue
    }

    required init(value: T) {
        super.init(value: value)
    }
}
```

So far so good. I go about defining such an enum that conforms to that protocol, and set up my fields:

```
enum AppleType: String, EnumProtocol {
    case RedDelicious = "red"
    case Honeycrisp = "honeycrisp"

    static func getValueFromString(value: String) -> EnumProtocol {
        if value == "red" {
            return AppleType.RedDelicious
        } else {
            return AppleType.Honeycrisp
        }
    }
}

let nameField = TextField(value: "Will Clarke")
var appleField = EnumField<AppleType>(value: .RedDelicious)
```

This is all working as expected. I have a TextField object, and an EnumField object.

In my main form though, I have an array of all the fields on that form. I want to loop through them and do something different depending on their actual type.

```
var fieldArray: [FieldProtocol] = [appleField, nameField]

for field in fieldArray {
    if let validField = field as? TextField {
        print(validField.value)
    } else if let validField = field as? WHAT GOES HERE??? {
        print(validField.value.rawValue)
    }
}
```

My question, obviously, is what to put in "WHAT GOES HERE???" Semantically, what I want is "an EnumField that uses any object conforming to EnumField", which I assumed would be "EnumField". But that doesn't work.

I tried just "EnumField" but Xcode complains that "'EnumField ?' does not conform to protocol 'EnumField'".

There's gotta be a way to do this... right?

You can take all the code and put it into a Playground - it should all work other than the line in question.

Comment: But if you're defining both the Enum and the "TextField" to conform the FieldProtocol… why do you need that validField? Why not just (inside the loop) use `print(field.stringRepresentation)` ?

Comment: I have to run atm, but I can take a look later (I'm not a Swift expert) but I would perhaps try to use a generic protocol (through Associated Types, since that's how you do it). https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_234

Comment: Yeah I use the protocol functions most of the time, but in occasional cases I need to get the exact types. In my current example, I need to write them to a server. This is a vastly oversimplified example of what I'm doing.